# how to store data to SQL database using jsp?

Tags: html, sql, jsp

How to store the values to SQL database using jsp ?

How to get the details from html table and store it in  SQL database using jsp ?

```
<table>
      <tr>
        <td width="50%" align="center">Company Name  : </td>
        <td width="50%"><input type="text" name="companyname" /></td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="50%" align="center">Contact Name   : </td>
        <td width="50%"><input type="text" name="contactname" /></td>
       <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><button type="submit">SUBMIT</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Please include the relevant code in your question.

Comment: I need Jsp Code to store the textbox values of html page into sql server database

Comment: _"I need Jsp Code"_ Then write it, SO isn't a free coding service. Please give http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Then you need to write a servlet to do the Job for you.